# Using grep in list in order to fill a new df in R

Tags: r, dataframe

Hello I have a list :

```
list=c("OK_67J","GGT_je","Ojj_OK_778","JUu3","JJE")
```

and i would like to transforme it as a df :

```
COL1        COL2 
OK_67J      A
GGT_je      B
Ojj_OK_778  A
JUu3        B
JJE         B
```

where I add a A if there is the `OK_`pattern and B if not.

I tried :

```
COL2<-rep("Virus",length(list))
list[grep("OK_",tips)]<-"A"

df <- data.frame(COL1=list,COL2=COL2)
```

Comment: `col2 <- ifelse(grepl('OK_', list), 'A', 'B')`  will return `"A" "B" "A" "B" "B"  `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `grepl` :

```
ifelse(grepl('OK_', list), "A", "B")
#[1] "A" "B" "A" "B" "B"
```

You can also do it without `ifelse` :

```
c("B", "A")[grepl('OK_', list) + 1]
```

It is better to not use variable name as `list` since it's a default function in R.

Answer (score 2):

When you exchange your `list[grep("OK_",tips)]<-"A"` with `COL2[grep("OK_",list)] <- "A"` your solution will work.

```
list  <- c("OK_67J", "GGT_je", "Ojj_OK_778", "JUu3", "JJE")

COL2 <- rep("B", length(list))
COL2[grep("OK_", list)] <- "A"
df <- data.frame(COL1 = list, COL2 = COL2)
df
#        COL1 COL2
#1     OK_67J    A
#2     GGT_je    B
#3 Ojj_OK_778    A
#4       JUu3    B
#5        JJE    B
```

Answer (score 1):

First off, `list` is not a list but a character vector:

```
list=c("OK_67J","GGT_je","Ojj_OK_778","JUu3","JJE")
class(list)
[1] "character"
```

To transform it to a dataframe:

```
df <- data.frame(v1 = list)
```

To add the new column use `grepl`:

```
df$v2 <- ifelse(grepl("OK_", df$v1), "A", "B")
```

or use `str_detect`:

```
library(stringr)
df$v2 <- ifelse(str_detect(df$v1, "OK_"), "A", "B")
```

Result:

```
df
          v1 v2
1     OK_67J  A
2     GGT_je  B
3 Ojj_OK_778  A
4       JUu3  B
5        JJE  B
```